# XML File Editing

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am doing eclipse plug-in development. I am editting an XML file. I have two options:

1. Use XStream to edit the existing XML file.
2. Use DOM parser like DocumentBuilderFactory to edit the XML file
3. ??? Is there a better option?

I am inserting a dependency into an ivy.xml

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to modify a file's contents *programmatically*? XStream sounds like overkill for working with XML and only XML.

Comment: Yes - In one case I am using XStream to edit an ivy.xml file.. In another case, I am using DocumentBuilderFactory.